# Generating JSON schema from Moose classes

Tags: perl, jsonschema, moose

I have perl Moose classes. I am able to generate Moose objects for each class from JSON data ( `JSON->new->convert_blessed->utf8->pretty->encode($mooseObj);` ) and also generate JSON documents from Moose objects ( `bless( JSON->new->decode($json), 'CLASS_NAME' );` ).

However, I am not able to find a way to generate JSON schema from Moose classes. I need this schema for each Moose class, so that the browser client validates JSON data being sent to the server side. Currently, my approach is to hand-code JSON schema, but it has many drawbacks (every time Moose classes change, JSON schema needs updates; manual errors; time consuming; kinda difficult for nested classes; not able to map enum types; etc.). I see posts on generating JSON schema from Java class, C# class, XSD, Objective C class, etc. but not from perl or Moose classes. Any information on this is appreciated.

Comment: What you describe is the wrong way around. Your example for generating an object is the code for storing. Also, that approach is not very smart as the additional Moose behavior and all the MOP stuff is not going to work properly if you simply `bless` into a package that uses Moose. You should use https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Storage instead. It's for exactly that purpose.

Comment: In terms of your actual question, this is going to be hard. The types that Moose uses (or can use) are not something that is included with Perl. They are usually just functions that validate something. As soon as you deviate from the ones that Moose brings it's going to be... tricky, unless you include serialization meta magic in your types. If you have that, you should be able to write something that uses the MOP to walk a class recursively to spit out JSON schema. If you do, please release it on CPAN.